# Protractor doesn't start tried all the solutions given on internet

Tags: node.js, protractor, webdriver-manager

```
Below are my env details:
OS : win 10 64 bit
npm version - 5.3.0
node version - v8.3.0
webdriver-manager version - 
chromedriver: 103.0.5060.53, 104.0.5112.29 (latest)
geckodriver: 0.31.0 (latest)
selenium: 4.0.0-alpha-1 (latest)

chrome browser version - 103.0.5060.114
```

// Getting below error whenever I try to run tests, I tried with different node and webdriver-manager versions, nothing is working, I tried from scratch,

```
n\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example>node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
module.js:491
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:578:3
```

Comment: Were you trying to run `webdriver-manager update` from the the example folder? Double check the path, it is relative to your current location.

Answer (score 0):

your example folder doesn't have node_modules.
try this instead

```
node ./../node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```